# Misuse of the [database] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[16 questions](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database+data-request) use both [database](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) and [data-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request).

While these questions are undeniably data requests, I feel like [database](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) should not be applied to these questions:

> A database is an organized collection of data. The data are typically organized to model relevant aspects of reality in a way that supports processes requiring this information. For example, modelling the availability of rooms in hotels in a way that supports finding a hotel with vacancies.

Should we do something about it?

Comment: misuse + database = [databuse]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [database](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) tag is still being applied to far too many questions that are actually just a [data-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request). In its current form, it is of no use to anyone.

For this reason I have renamed the tag to [sql](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql), since most of the questions actually talk about SQL databases anyway. I've also gone through all relevant questions and changed the ones that were mislabeled.

Answer (score 3):

If there is no opposition within 48 hours, I will remove the [database](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) tag from the questions that I think don't deserve it and that are also tagged [data-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request).

Comment: Thanks for taking the initiative :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to remove the tag. I think people are using it as another way of focusing the request.  Since we don't have "data" or "dataset", this seems like a reasonable tag and the use in most of these questions.

Comment: The *database* tag is fine for questions that are specifically about databases, such as [Enron Email Dataset in MySQL](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/enron-email-dataset-in-mysql). As Nicolas mentioned, many (but not all) of the questions currently tagged *database* are actually just *data-request* questions with no focus on databases.

Comment: @JeanneHolm: I admit I might not be understanding fully what the *database* tag is about. I think the tag description needs to be clarified to say what is OK and what is not. If we allow too large a definition, it will apply to most questions on this site. What is your definition of this tag?